# How to add value to first column in csv file through shell script

Tags: linux, shell, csv

Am trying to add value to the first column to the existing file and i need only the value should be in the first column alone not all the columns.

**Existing**

```
col1,col2,col3
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

**Expected**

```
col0,col1,col2,col3
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

The 1,2,3 values are belongs to col1,col2 and so on and the first column alone should be updated which i like and the other values should be left blank.

I tried it using the sed utility but it is taking the complete row into account.

Comment: "column" usually refers to the vertical axis. You appear to have updated only the first **row** (horizontal axis). Show your sed command so that people can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: @jhnc Actually the csv file is getting generated by running git commands and i need to update only first row first column alone and rest of the mappings should be as such i tried with sed but it substitutes for the complete first row

Answer (score 1):

If you want to prepend something to just the first **row** with `sed`:

```
$ sed '1s/^/col0,/' input.csv
col0,col1,col2,col3
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

The `1` before the `s//` command means it'll only be run on the first line.

Comment: Thanks @shawn, may be i didnt put the correct view, i need the column name in first row and first column only and the column values should be empty. But when i try to run this the col1 values getting merged with col0.

Comment: Perhaps: `sed 's/^/,/;1s//col0/' input.csv`

Comment: It worked @jhnc, may be if you could add some comments for the understanding it will be helpful. Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the task is:

- prepend a new non-empty column to first row of a csv file
- prepend a new empty column to all other rows

With sed you can do:

```
sed <input.csv >output.csv '
    s/^/,/    # prepend empty column to every row
    1s//col0/ # on row(line) 1 add the header text
              #    (empty regex means reuse previous one)
              # implicit print
'
```

With your sample input:

```
col1,col2,col3
1,2,3
4,5,6
```

output will be:

```
col0,col1,col2,col3
,1,2,3
,4,5,6
```

Note that the CSV may become corrupted if any fields contain embedded newlines.